# Lua checking variable during for loop

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I apologize in advance since I am sure this has been answered already but with without any programming experience it is difficult for me to translate a solution from other posts into my own code. I have a for loop that I want to check a global variable during each interval. The code below does not work since it thinks "continue_loop" is a local variable. Any suggestions?

```
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
continue_loop = 1
Click()
end

if (event == "M_RELEASED" and arg == 3) then
Click()
end

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1) then
Stopclick()
end

function Stopclick()
continue_loop = 0
end

function Click()
    PressMouseButton(1)
    Sleep (10)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
  for i=1,10 do
    if (continue_loop == 1) then
        MoveMouseRelative(0,5)
        Sleep (30)
    else return
    end
    end
  if (continue_loop == 0) then
    Stopclick()
  elseif (continue_loop == 1) then SetMKeyState(3)
  else Stopclick()
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you expect `continue_loop` to be anything other than `0` or `1` if you only ever set it to either of those two?

Comment: I don't expect it to be any other value than `0` or `1`. Basically I just want to be able to break the loop if needed before it finishes and this is what I came up with. I don't know programming so I am sure there are much more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a `local continue_loop` at the beginning of your program. 
I would suggest you to learn something about **Visibility Scope and Lifetime of Variables** to better understand this solution!

Comment: I actually do have `local continue_loop = 0` earlier in the script but that doesn't seem to affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

lua only has a single thread, that means during your for loop the continue_loop variable will not change because no code attempts to change it inside the loop.

You will need to call a function which checks the mouse state and then update the continue_loop variable.

```
for i=1,10 do
    CheckMouseState() -- sets global value of continue_loop based on mouse state.
    if (continue_loop == 1) then
        MoveMouseRelative(0,5)
        Sleep (30)
    else return
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you very much. I think this is the missing piece to get my script to work.